# Matlab contour plot going to infinity for finite function $f(x_1,x_2)=e^x_1-(x_1x_2)+x_2^2$

Tags: optimization, graphing-functions, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

The following function that we wanted to plot was not appearing on the plot properly. The function is as follows:
$$f(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1}-(x_1x_2)+x_2^2$$
Since the function is parabolic, exponential, and rectangular hyperbolic the function should have some curves associated with it and not straight lines. What could be the possible error and here is the matlab code.

```
i=linspace(-200,200);
j=linspace(-200,200);
[X,Y]= meshgrid(i,j);
Z = exp(X)-(X*Y)+(Y^2);
contour(X,Y,Z)
```

[image: Contour plot for the above mentioned function]

Comment: For large ranges, you can explicitly define the contour levels in the 4th argument. Also, on line 4, you are using matrix operations which will be different to the original values. I think you want `Z = exp(X)-(X.*Y)+(Y.^2)` to perform elementwise operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the range of your function, e.g. take the first term, it will change from $e^{-200}$ to $e^{200}$ that is a factor $e^{400} \sim 10^{173}$, which obviously is hard to resolve.

Here's an example with a smaller range

[image]

**EDIT**
This is the code I used to generate the plot above, it is `python`'s matplotlib which provides a MATLAB-like interface

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmin, xmax = -2.0, 2.0
ymin, ymax = -2.0, 2.0

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 50, endpoint = True), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 50, endpoint = True))
z = np.exp(x) - x * y + y * y
plt.contour(x, y, z, color = 'k')
plt.imshow(z, cmap='jet', extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), origin = 'lower', alpha = 0.3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, For the clarification. Still in the learning process. And can you provide the code also for the above. Just to see out of curiosity.

Comment: In MATLAB, observe also that you should write `Z = exp(X)-(X.*Y)+(Y.^2);` with the dots, to indicate an element-wise operation. Otherwise, it will do a matrix multiplication, and that is not what you want.

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime Happy to help, what I attached is a python code. Do you still want to see it?

Comment: I would love to see it @caverac

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime Done!